# Why does Surefire not find any tests when upgrading to JUnit 5?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

There are common reasons why the subject question might be happening, but this is not a typical situation.

We had many services with working JUnit4 tests.  We are working on a process of upgrading multiple elements of our platform, including moving from Java 8 to Java 11, and JUnit 4 to mostly JUnit 5.

I am looking at two services that we've worked on converting.  In both cases, we are using all the artifacts in junit-bom-5.8.2, and both with Java 11.  We are also using maven-surefire-plugin v3.0.0-M6.  We need a fix for running test suites that is only available in that version.

In one service, we converted many of the tests from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, but not all of them.  We are managing to get all of these tests to succeed.

In another service, all of the tests were converted to JUnit 5.  In that case, an odd thing happens when we run the tests from mvn.  It simply says:

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I tried running with "-X".  That didn't tell me anything useful.

We have a "UnitTestSuite" class that contains all, or at least most, of our unit test classes.  I ran that from the command line.  For every test it tried to execute there, it said:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
```

The fact that it thinks this is a JUnit 4 test is obviously a clue, but I don't know what it means.

Note that one of the dependencies we are loading is the `junit-vintage-engine`, but we are loading that with the other service with mixed JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests.

It almost seems as if the service has mixed JUnit 4 and JUnit 5, it chooses the correct runner for each, but if the service ONLY has JUnit 5 tests, it only chooses the JUnit 4 runner.

We are loading the vintage engine in our parent pom. I will work on building a version that excludes that, just to see if that's what's happening, but that will be a big pain if that's really what we have to do.

I went through the steps to ensure that the vintage engine was not provided, but it didn't change anything.  It's still failing to find any runnable methods.

For instance, here is a somewhat elided excerpt of the first test class that it says it can't find any runnable methods for:

```
...
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
...

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class ...Test {

    @InjectMocks
    ...

    @Mock
    private ...

    ...

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void getCrmResponse_success() throws Exception {
```

And note again, the "no runnable methods" exception occurs in the `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` class, so it's confused about what JUnit to use for this.

I tried adding a dummy JUnit 4 test, and this was the only test it found:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ PlatformPilotMs ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running ...DummyTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.102 s - in ...DummyTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: From your description, I don't see any mention of [adding jupiter engine as documented for surefire plugin junit5 support](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html). Have you added it?

Comment: "we are using all the artifacts in junit-bom-5.8.2". This includes jupiter and the corresponding junit-platform artifacts.

Comment: so you really use *all of them*? like `junit-platform-jfr` and other exotic ones? how exactly do you use them?

Comment: I literally pasted the entire contents of the "dependencies" block from junit-bom-5.8.2 into the dependencies block of my service.  Just because those artifacts are present doesn't mean I'm "using them".  I don't know what the "Jfr" artifact is for.

Comment: Can you please post a full pom and also the things of your parent pom ... furthermore you have to use `junit-jupiter-engine` See also https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html (api is not enough)

Comment: The JFR dep is not needed....

Comment: "Just because those artifacts are present doesn't mean I'm "using them"." then please don't say you use all of them if that's not what you are doing. There seems to be some confusion what you are exactly using and what not.

Comment: Hopefully it is clear now. To ensure I was overriding all the versions specified by Spring, I pasted the entire contents of that bom into my pom.  This is working fine in the service that has both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests.  This service, with only JUnit 5 tests, is the one that is not working.

Comment: Overriding versions of spring boot (I suppose) is much easier via defining the BOM of junit jupiter before the bom file of spring boot (except you are using spring boot as a parent)... If you have JUnit 4 test you have to add the junit-vintage-engine to execute the JUNit 4 tests...

Comment: it's really not clear until you post your maven configuration - you probably have in some way messed up your pom(s). You're not supposed to paste bom contents into your own pom dependency section, bom is about dependencyManagement.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but simply referring to the junit-bom as an import in my service didn't work. It still ended up with the older versions.

Comment: Furthermore a remark about your given test because you are using `TestPropertySource`. which usually only makes sense if you have a spring boot test...but here you only use mockito. Can you explain why you are using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in your beforeEach method? If you use the Mockito Extension you don't need to do this manually...

Comment: I'm aware of that. This was written by someone else. Clearly, how mockito initializes its mocks won't matter if it never executes the test.

Comment: I added some more info about running a JUnit 4 test. I would include the entire pom (with elisions), but it's 229k, much more than the limit.

Comment: Did you add the junit-vintage-engine to the plugin dependencies of the surefire plugin as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#JUnit4_API_in_test_dependencies)? And according to the rest of the docs on that page it doesn't look like a good idea to copy literally just all the artifacts of the bom as your dependencies. When overriding the Spring Boot versions doesn't work the way you tried it first, for me this is a smell if "brute force" brings you one small step further.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the plugin dependency, but adding that made no difference.

Comment: Adding the junit-vintage-engine to the plugin dependenices is not needed. Best would be to make a minimal spring boot setup which contains the same setup and put it on github or alike... it's easier than dicussing this here...

Answer (score 3):

Uou will have to tell Surefire plugin to use the correct test provider, for JUnit 5, it would be surefire-junit-platform

Add the following dependency for the Surefire plugin to select JUnit Jupiter.

```
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Reference:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/providers.html